# creating a new dataframe each time and applying sum

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, pandas

I am creating a new dataframe each time through loops so that I can calculate the sum but I am getting wrong answers as the data is quite huge (around 3 million rows)
Is there anyother approach to this ?:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(
    "SELECT DISTINCT SYMBOL FROM tableA WHERE TIM ==?;",
    conn, params={datetime_object}
)

for sym in df.SYMBOL:
    df2 = pd.read_sql_query(
        "SELECT SYMBOL,OPEN FROM tableA WHERE TIM ==? AND SYMBOL ==? AND EXP==?;",
        conn, params={datetime_object,sym,exp}
    )
    Total = df2['OPEN'].sum()
```

I am getting correct sum for few rows but 0 as for others, I think some memory issue!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to format your code better. You can do it with control (cmd) + k (select the code first) or simply 4-space indentation. Secondly, what kind you wrong answers you get?  What is the hypothesis you have currently? What kind of answers you expect? can you give us some example input and expected output?

Comment: From your question it's not entirely clear to me what the problem is, so here's some general advice I think can help you. If you think the data volume causes an issue, you can use the 'chunksize' arg in pd.read_sql_query() and update a running sum variable. Also, maybe look into `sqlalchemy` instead of pandas, if all you do with the data is to return one number. If this doesn't help, please try to elaborate what you're trying to do and what you're getting instead of the correct output.